# Removing enterprise enrollment from chromebook

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os, acer

I recently moved and my school said I would keep my Chromebook. The only problem is that they left the enterprise enrollment on. They told me to remove it, but I didn't manage. I have an Acer cb5 312t. I have already tried this. I have done it twice and I unplugged the battery connector and even the entire battery. It still wouldn't work. I even had it without the batter for over an hour. Is there some screw or something I am missing? Is there maybe a CMOS battery of sorts I have to remove or something? Please help me! I know I can replace the SSD, but I don't wanna invest SSD money into it. Another thing is that it has a take-home policy of sorts which allows it to unblock during non-school hours, but I have moved timezones so it doesn't work well. Any help would be apreciated!

Make sure your Chromebook is off.

Unscrew your Chromebook back cover.

Unscrew the battery and unplug the power cord connecting the battery and the motherboard.

Open your Chromebook and press the power button for 30 seconds. This should bypass the admin block.

Place the battery back in and connect the power cords. Put the back cover on.

Turn your Chromebook on and press esc + refresh + power It may take 9-15 minutes to boot based on your device. Do not follow this step until you reach the chrome screen.

When you reach the "Chrome Os is missing or damaged" screen press Ctrl + d.

Comment: I swear this gets asked every week. You need to take it back to the enterprise, and have them un-enroll it.

Comment: Your school will need to follow the [instructions to deprovision the device.](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3523633#zippy=%2Cdeprovision-a-device)